# Which is more fundamental: $H$ or $B$?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_field), $B$ is called the

Magnetic flux density / Magnetic induction / Magnetic field,

while $H$ is called the

Magnetic field intensity / Magnetic field strength / Magnetic field / Magnetizing field.

Which of them is more fundamental? Is it meaningful to say one is more fundamental than other?

Comment: Define "fundamental".

Comment: which is the independent quantity.

Comment: Neither is more fundamental. The electromagnetic field is more fundamental. And four-potential is even _more_ fundamental. See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aharonov%E2%80%93Bohm_effect#Global_action_vs._local_forces).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the equation $\mathbf \nabla \times \mathbf H = \mathbf J_\textrm{free}$, and at the same time at $\mathbf \nabla \times\mathbf B = \mu_0 \mathbf J$. Now, $\mathbf J = \mathbf J_\textrm{bound} + \mathbf J_\textrm{free}$, and $\mathbf H = \frac1\mu_o \mathbf B - \mathbf M$, where $\mathbf M$ is called the **Magnetisation**. $\mathbf H$ allows me to write the **Ampere's Law** in terms of *free* current alone, and that is the thing that we control directly.

So for problems having specific symmetry I can immediately write $\mathbf H$, and from there $\mathbf B$.So in the laboratory people will talk more about $\mathbf H$ than $\mathbf B$.

And to answer your question **both** are **fundamental**.

P.S. $\mathbf B = \mu \mathbf H$, $\mathbf M = \chi_m \mathbf H$ and $\mu = \mu_0(1+\chi_m)$.